# inner product space with subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra

$(X, \langle\cdot,\cdot \rangle)$. $U$ and $V$ are subspaces of $X$ such that $U\perp V$. Then:
a. $U\cap V= \{0\}$
b. $X=U\oplus V$
c. If $x=u+v$ for $u\in U$ and $v\in V$, then $||x||^2 = ||u||^2 + ||v||^2$

a. 
It is true, lets suppose that there is exists $v$ such that $v\in V$ and $v\in U$. Then $\langle v, v\rangle=0$, however $\forall_{v\in V\setminus \{0\}} \langle v,v\rangle > 0$. Hence, $v=0$.

b. is true, because a. is true

c. is true, because: 
$||x|| = ||u+v||$
$$
||x||^2 = ||u+v||^2=\langle u+v, u+v\rangle =\\
\langle u, u+v\rangle + \langle v, u+v\rangle =\\ 
\langle u+v, u\rangle + \langle u+v, v\rangle =\\
\langle u,u \rangle+ \langle u,v\rangle+ \langle u,v \rangle + \langle v,v\rangle =\\ 
||u||^2 + 0 + 0 + ||v||^2 = ||u||^2 + ||v||^2
$$

Am I ok ?

Comment: I don't think b. is necessarily true, consider the subspaces, $U$ and $V$ of $\mathbb{R}^3$ that are the $x$-axis and $y$-axis respectively. They are orthogonal, yet $U \oplus V\neq\mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: Ok, $U = span([1,0,0]), V=span([0,1,0])$. From what you knwo that $V\perp U$ ?

Comment: Another simpler counterexample: $U=V=\{0\}$. $\mid $$X=U\oplus V$ means $U\cap V = \{0\}$ (which you indeed have) but also $X=Span(U\cup V)$ (and there is no reason for that to be true).

Comment: @HaskellFun it suffices to note that
$$
\langle [1,0,0], [0,1,0]\rangle = 0
$$
That is, there are basis $\{u_i\},\{v_j\}$ for $U$ and $V$ such that $\langle u_i,v_j \rangle = 0$ for all $i,j$.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom, from what you know that $\langle [1,0,0], [0,1,0]\rangle = 0$

Comment: @HaskellFun in this context, our inner product of choice is the traditional inner product on $\Bbb R^3$, which is to say the dot product.  All I'm saying is that the dot product of those two vectors is $0$.

Comment: Do you mean $1 \cdot 0 + 0 \cdot 1 + 0 \cdot 0 = 0$?

Comment: That's exactly what I mean.